# Is it possible to add @JvmOverloads to the generated copy(...) method in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, copy, immutability

Suppose I have the following Kotlin class:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Because this is a `data` class, a method with the following signature will be automatically generated:

```
fun copy(firstName: String = this.firstName, lastName: String = this.lastName): Person
```

Now, I'd like to call this method from Java code, like:

```
Person john = new Person("John", "Smith");
Person adam = john.copy("Adam");
```

I am expecting to have two `Person` objects now: "John Smith" and "Adam Smith".

Sadly, the `copy` method does not have overloaded variants and I don't see any way to add them via `@JvmOverloads`.

So far I've tried to overload it and create an extension, but it is shadowed and works like a static method in Java (plus there's a lot of boilerplate):

```
@JvmOverloads
fun Person.copy(firstName: String = this.firstName, lastName: String = this.lastName): Person {
    return this.copy(firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName)
}
```

Is it possible to do in a way that doesn't require too much code to be written?

Comment: No, i don't think there is any other way

Comment: As of Kotlin 1.3 there is no possibility to customize the generation of data class methods.

Comment: @yole I'm looking at the changelogs and can't find any mention of this. Could you please add a link?

Comment: Any mention of what? There was never a possibility to customize this; nothing changed in 1.3. I'm just specifying a version number in my comment in case the possibility is added later

Comment: @yole oh, okay, I misunderstood, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

No. But we can override the copy method by ourselves. Like this:

```
data class CustomTextInfo(
    val text: String,
    val textColor: Int,
    val backgroundColor: Int,
    val fontId: Int
) {
    fun copy(): CustomTextInfo {
        return CustomTextInfo(text, textColor, backgroundColor, fontId)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to write everything by hand I wouldn't be using Kotlin (;

Comment: now it's not possible to provide copy impl: `Providing explicit implementations for the componentN() and copy() functions is not allowed.` source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html